# Passing the json object to a Asp.net mvc Controller

Tags: knockout-mvc

I want to pass a json object to a Controller through Ajax post method in a Asp.net MVC project.But Ajax post method fails to send the json object to the controller.How can i pass the json oject properly to the controller using Ajax post method?

Comment: can you provide your JS\Knockout code and controlller method? your question is very generic. some code would help us with answering it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data = new Object();
 data.Name = "Bla";
 data.Surname="Bla";//This is our view model
 $.post("/api/controller/action",data,function(result){alert(result);},"json");
```

The wep api controller or controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult ActionName(MyViewModel model)
{
 return Ok("yuppiiii");
}
```